# Can I use a wired keyboard with a wireless receiver for a keyboard and mouse combo?

Tags: keyboard, wireless-mouse, wireless-keyboard

I have a single receiver for a wireless HP keyboard and mouse combo. The space bar on this wireless keyboard is hard to hit, so I would like to switch to a wired keyboard instead. But I would still like to use my wireless mouse, so the receiver will stay plugged into my desktop. I have not tried the switch yet because I am worried that it may damage my tower, keyboard, or receiver (I do not claim to be hardware-savvy).

Can I use a wired keyboard with a receiver for a wireless keyboard and mouse combo? Also, my wireless keyboard does not have a built-in switch to turn it off, so will I have to remove the batteries to disable it? Does Superuser field beginner questions like these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are correct, it will just behave as if there were two keyboards connected to your computer where each would be active for typing in. It will not harm or mess up your computer. If you want you may remove the batteries from the wireless keyboard if you do not want the old wireless keyboard to interact with your computer.

SuperUser is okay with your "beginner" questions, we hold no prejudice against such questions unless they are *generally* broad, off-topic and show little to no effort in trying to comprehend their dilemma or demonstrate a complete fallacy in logic flow. I am not a mod, but that seems to be the case.